# Get 10 most common Numbers from a column

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

What I'm trying to do: Get top 10 most used color ints inside the column.

---

I'm connecting to a SQL Server database and I need to get some values from a table column

1. I have a column inside a data table, lets call it "Cars"
2. Inside the table I have a column called "Date" and "Color"
3. The "Color" column has different values ranging from 0 to 20 Each number inside the color column stands for a color code.

| Date | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | 0 |
| 2022-09-01 | 3 |
| 2022-09-01 | 8 |
| 2022-09-01 | 15 |
| 2022-09-01 | 20 |
| 2022-09-01 | 1 |

First: I'm checking how many new rows appeared as of today with:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection(connString);

using (connection)
{
    connection.Open();

    // Total Queries
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [db].[Cars] WHERE Date LIKE '" + today + "%'", connection))  
    {
        var aa = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        Console.WriteLine("Total car orders today: "  + aa);
    }
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is get the `TOP 10` most used numbers inside the color column. But what I'm getting is either the lowest number or the highest number.

My code below:

```
using (var cmmd = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT Color, COUNT (Color) AS ValueFrequency FROM [dbo].[Cars] WHERE QueriedAt LIKE '" + today + "%' GROUP BY Color ORDER BY ValueFrequency ASC", connection))  
{
    var bb = Convert.ToInt32(cmmd.ExecuteScalar());
    Console.WriteLine("Top 10 colors today : "  + bb);
}
```

What I'm getting is either the highest or lowest color int inside the column and not the list of top 10 most appeared colors in my console.
I would like to have top 10 most colors printed out in a list.

Comment: There needs to be a **space** before the `ORDER BY` clause in your second query!

Comment: Also: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: `QueriedAt LIKE '" + today + "%'` is the worst you can do; change `Like` into `QueriedAt = @prm_QueriedAt` and then assign *query parameter*

Comment: Why can't you try selecting the top 5 by sorting the no of colors ? Will that work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the top 5 colors of today, shouldn't you simply order by frequency desc?

```
SELECT TOP 5 Color, COUNT (Color) AS ValueFrequency 
FROM [dbo].[Cars] 
WHERE [Date] >= CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) AND [Date] < CAST( DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()) AS Date )
GROUP BY Color 
ORDER BY ValueFrequency DESC
```

Comment: Tried this way but I am getting only one number and not a list of top 5

Comment: Really? This looks ok: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/346c0/4

Comment: This should work @Mrks

Answer (score -1):

you need to use group by color and sort descending

```
CREATE TABLE tableName 
(
    Date    date,
    Color   int,
    Cars    int
);

INSERT INTO tableName (Date ,Color,Cars) VALUES ('2022-09-01 ', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO tableName (Date ,Color,Cars) VALUES ('2022-09-01 ', '3', '2');
INSERT INTO tableName (Date ,Color,Cars) VALUES ('2022-09-01 ', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO tableName (Date ,Color,Cars) VALUES ('2022-09-01 ', '15', '1');
INSERT INTO tableName (Date ,Color,Cars) VALUES ('2022-09-01 ', '20', '3');
INSERT INTO tableName (Date ,Color,Cars) VALUES ('2022-09-01 ', '1', '1');


select top 10 date,color,count(color) as ccnt  from tablename group by date,color order by ccnt desc
```

Comment: But I am not inserting anything to the table. I'm only "reading" it.

Comment: @Mrks You don't need the insert, you only need the select. the insert in the answer is to build your sample data into a query so he can test his select

Comment: as @GuidoG said , its for the SO users to test the sample data and query ., if its satisfies them then they approve the post as answer.

Answer (score -3):

Try `SELECT TOP 5 Color, COUNT(Color) AS ValueFrequency from table` rest where clause/conditions

this will return the top 5 rows

Comment: With no `ORDER BY` that will return 5 **arbitrary** rows.

Comment: @Larnu you should keep the rest of the conditions after the table_name, I just gave an example query

Comment: Why not, instead, actually write the whole query? Also, my comment was aimed at your [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73568153/1), which was simply: *"Try `SELECT TOP 5 from table`

this will return top 5 rows"* Which has other problems in addition to the omission of the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: The `order by` is a crucial part of the solution, it can not be missing

Comment: @Mrks is using asc in the query , so it will return the 5 arbitrary rows , if you want the most bought car color you should use desc.